# Can Debian linux find automaticaly drivers for USB ethernet NIC?

Tags: linux, debian, drivers

Can Debian linux find automaticaly drivers for USB ethernet NIC?

Which would you recommend me? My problem is, on my datastore, there is only 100mbps network, no free PCI slots, so last chance how to speedup my datastore is to add next USB NIC.

Is it useful to buy 1Gbps NIC to USB if usb 2.0 has only 480mbps speed ?
Or actually, is it better, than buy USB NIC 100mbps ?

Do you think, could I use it with debian for loadbalancing? Is there support in drivers for loadbalancing? Next solution is to add about 3 or 4 USB nic, that could make solution .-)

Comment: Is there anything less demanding on data rate that could be shuffled over to USB? Just sayin'.

Comment: Problem solved. It found drivers without problems, my friend borrowed me his one NIC to USB 100mbps and it is working. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Debian linux find automaticaly drivers for USB ethernet NIC?

Depends. Linux/Debian has drivers for many USB Network Adapters. YOu should search for some supported devices.

> Is it useful to buy 1Gbps NIC to USB if usb 2.0 has only 480mbps speed ?

It should work better than 100 MBit/s, but a PCIe-1Gbs-Card would be better.